# Prepare my data for HighStocks data series input

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, highcharts

I am trying to find a way to parse my data format so that it could be recognized by HighStocks. My data fetched from the server is in such format:

```
var data = [
    {
        "dt":"2010-06-10 14:33:39",
        "val":98
    },
    {
        "dt":"2010-06-10 14:34:18",
        "val":99
    },
    {
        "dt":"2010-06-10 14:34:28",
        "val":93
    },
    {
        "dt":"2010-06-10 14:34:38",
        "val":79
    },
    {
        "dt":"2010-06-10 14:34:48",
        "val":87
    },
    {
        "dt":"2010-06-10 14:34:58",
        "val":86
    },
    {
        "dt":"2010-06-10 14:35:08",
        "val":79
    },
    {
        "dt":"2010-06-10 14:35:17",
        "val":90
    }]
```

From the demo on Highcharts website it accepts format like:

```
var usdeur = [
[Date.UTC(2003,8,24),0.8709],
[Date.UTC(2003,8,25),0.872],
[Date.UTC(2003,8,26),0.8714],
[Date.UTC(2003,8,29),0.8638],
[Date.UTC(2003,8,30),0.8567],
[Date.UTC(2003,9,1),0.8536],
[Date.UTC(2003,9,2),0.8564],
[Date.UTC(2003,9,3),0.8639],
[Date.UTC(2003,9,6),0.8538],
[Date.UTC(2003,9,7),0.8489]]
```

So simply saying, how could I format my data `2010-06-10 14:33:39` to `Date.UTC(2010,06,10,14,33,39)`? Any JavaScript/jQuery method or existing libraries like date.js/moment.js allow me to do that easily (say if I don't want to use `getUTC*()` to get the datetime information and then put into `Date.UTC()`)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you format it on your sql ? It's much better than format each point of your chart.
`UNIX_TIMESTAMP` should help you.
**Example**:
`SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(concat(dateColumn, timeColumn)) * 1000 AS 'dateUTC';`

Comment: I am just working on the chart generating, but someone is working on returning the data from the database. So by using the syntax you provided, then the date format could be formatted from `2010-06-10 14:33:39` to `Date.UTC(2010,06,10,14,33,39)` which is the format required for HighCharts